# Can someone explain how recursion works when finding all subsets?

Tags: c++, recursion

I cannot, for the life of me, picture recursion and what it's doing. I struggle with this a lot. From the *Competitive Programmer's Handbook*, I uncovered the following snippet of code in C++ as a solution to the following problem:

> Consider the problem of generating all subsets of a set of n elements.
>   For example, the subsets of {0,1,2} are ;, {0}, {1}, {2}, {0,1},
>   {0,2}, {1,2} and {0,1,2}.
>
> An elegant way to go through all subsets of a set is to use recursion.
>   The following function search generates the subsets of the set
>   {0,1,...,n − 1}. The function maintains a vector subset that will
>   contain the elements of each subset. The search begins when the
>   function is called with parameter 0.
>
> When the function search is called with parameter k, it decides
>   whether to include the element k in the subset or not, and in both
>   cases, then calls itself with parameter k + 1 However, if k = n, the
>   function notices that all elements have been processed and a subset
>   has been generated.

```cpp
void search(int k) {
    if (k == n) {
        // process subset
    } else {
        search(k+1);
        subset.push_back(k);
        search(k+1);
        subset.pop_back();
    }
}
```

So sure, this function works and I have done it about 3 times by hand to see that it does work flawlessly. But why?

Short of memorizing all recursive solutions for all problems I will never be able to come up with this kind of solution. What kind of abstraction is being made here? What is the more general concept that is being used here?

I've always struggled with recursion so any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `The function maintains a vector subset that will contain the elements of each subset.` How? Is it a global variable? I don't see any such variable declared in your snippet.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Sorry that's quoted from the book. So basically what that's saying I think is that there is only one vector. But if `k == n` is true then we can do whatever we want with this vector (and each subset's elements) I don't think it should be read into that much

Comment: The basic concept is that a problem can be broken into a smaller version of the same problem. For instance find all the subsets of a set of size n can be broken down into two problems of finding the all the subsets of a set of size n - 1. That's what your code is doing. All you have to realise is that when you are writing a function to solve a problem, you are allowed to call that function from inside itself.

Comment: Taking a much simpler problem, find if the letter `a` is inside a string `s`. That can be solved by asking is the first character of the string `s` the letter `a` or is it in the rest of the string (i.e is it in `s.substr(1)`) ? That's a recursive solution because you solved the problem of finding a letter in a string by finding the letter in another (shorter) string.

Comment: @john Ok. I've done Lisp related things like Scheme so I know what you're getting at with car and cdr/ first and rest... But it's hard to abstract that simple problem to here for me. This code still seems mystical to me which is why I'm asking for more detail.

Comment: Recursion is simple; it's just a function calling another function - except that the function it calls happens to be itself. But that's really no different than if it had called some other function.

Comment: @herophant Well the code is essentailly uses this fact, all_subsets(a1,a2,...,an) == all_subsets(a2,...,an) `U` {a1, all_subsets(a2,...,an)} where `U` is the set union operator. That's a recursive definition because all_subsets is defined in terms of itself. Now the code is a fairly direct translation of that definition. Is the problem that you don't see the definition is mathematically true? Or is it that you don't see how the code captures the definition?

Comment: @john The problem is: I cannot visualize the code. oo_miguel says to picture a binary tree but doing so even with height 3 seems impossible, there would be many intricacies and branches and I'm trying to grasp them all. The math makes sense although I'm not entirely sure how it's applicable here.

Comment: @herophant Well the two recursive calls in the code correspond to the two all_subsets on the RHS of the definition. One recursive call (the first) is made without ak inside the set and one is made with ak inside the set, again the corresponds to the definition above.

Comment: @herophant I'm not sure if this is going to help but a binary tree is also a recursive structure (because the two children of the root a binary tree are themselves binary trees). Maybe your mental block is that you are trying to grasp and visualise the whole thing, that's impossible. Recursion is a bit Zen like, you have to let go and trust that the recursive call works, you only have to understand the recursive function itself, not try and visualise the recursive function and all it's recursive calls.

Comment: Are you having a hard time grasping recursion in general, or just this problem?

Comment: @Chipster I know generally what recursion is, but having a hard time applying it to this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For each **k < n** we simply call `search(k+1)` recursively. once with the value **k** inside your set and once without it.

```
    search(k+1); // call search (k+1) with k NOT inside the set
    subset.push_back(k); // puts the value k inside the set
    search(k+1); // call search (k+1) with k inside the set
    subset.pop_back(); // removes the value k from the set
```

Once we reach **n==k** the recursion is terminated.

Imagine a binary tree of depth n, where each level represents the current value and the two branches, the decision if the value goes into your final set or not. The leaves represent all final sets.

So given **n=3** and starting with **k=0** you get:

```
search(0); 
-> search(1); // with 0 in
->-> search(2); // with 0 in AND 1 in
->->-> search (3); // with 0 in AND 1 in AND 2 in. terminates with (0,1,2)
->->-> search (3); // with 0 in AND 1 in AND 2 not in. terminates with (0,1)
->-> search(2); // with 0 in AND 1 not in
->->-> search (3); // with 0 in AND 1 not in AND 2 in. terminates with  (0,2)
->->-> search (3); // with 0 in AND 1 not in AND 2 not in. terminates with  (0)
-> search(1); // with 0 not in
->-> search(2); // with 0 not in AND 1 in
->->-> search (3); // with 0 not in AND 1 in AND 2 in. terminates with  (1,2)
->->-> search (3); // with 0 not in AND 1 in AND 2 not in. terminates with  (1)
->-> search(2); // with 0 not in AND 1 not in
->->-> search (3); // with 0 not in AND 1 not in AND 2 in. terminates with  (2)
->->-> search (3); // with 0 not in AND 1 not in AND 2 not in. terminates with  ()
```

As **john** smartly pointed out in his comment, the recursion uses the fact that:

*all_subsets(a1,a2,...,an) == all_subsets(a2,...,an) U {a1, all_subsets(a2,...,an)}* where *U* is the set union operator.

Many other mathematical definitions will translate into recursive calls naturally.

Comment: Isn't the trace backwards? We make the call where 0 is NOT in first, right? Why does it say 0 is in for the first call?

Comment: @herophant: yes exactly. sorry, I got the ordering wrong... seems you understand it ;)

Comment: When coming up with mathematical definitions like this, is it ideal to always start from the bottom? We started from  0 here and not from 3 for example i.e. a1 and not an

Comment: @herophant: It might often be better to start at the beginning/bottom, especially when you work with infinite lists. You can think of "taking n first elements" from an infinite list like: take n {a1,a2,a3...} =  take (n-1) {a2,a3,...} etc...

Comment: One question remains, and this probably has to do with me not understanding the stack (where all function calls are stored, including recursive). Why is `subset.pop_back();` necessary? Does this mean that when you are done with one instance of k, you will never call it again?

Comment: @herophant: each time the function is called. the paramaters and return address are put on the stack, so if your recursion gets to deep/nested you might get a stack overflow. This can be countered with tail-recursion which is a topic for another discussion ;). Once the recursion reaches the deepest level. It calls your "//process subset" code and goes back one level. (never returning there again)

Comment: This site's eponymous error : ). But stack overflow should not result if we are just meddling with subset, which is a vector. `subset.pop_back();` only happens in the last line, so after we reach the sets with length 3, only incorrect subsets shouold... But why do we need this? I'm not looking for an explanation of the stack, but this is probably intuitive in some way

Comment: @herophant: push_back() and pop_back() happen on each level for each possible combination of past push_back's() and pop_back's()  on higher levels!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are lacking is visualization. So I will suggest you to visit sites like [algorithm-visualizer.org](https://algorithm-visualizer.org/backtracking/sum-of-subsets) , [pythontutor.com](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html) .

You can paste this code snippet [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) and run it line by line so that you can understand how the code flow works.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void subsetsUtil(vector<int>& A, vector<vector<int> >& res, vector<int>& subset, int index) {
    res.push_back(subset);
    for (int i = index; i < A.size(); i++) {
        subset.push_back(A[i]);
        subsetsUtil(A, res, subset, i + 1);
    }
    return;
}

vector<vector<int> > subsets(vector<int>& A) {
    vector<int> subset;
    vector<vector<int> > res;
    int index = 0;
    subsetsUtil(A, res, subset, index);
    return res;
}

int32_t main() {
    vector<int> array = { 1, 2, 3 };
    vector<vector<int> > res = subsets(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < res[i].size(); j++)
            cout << res[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's good that you are really trying to learn. This will help you in competitive programming a lot. Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

This is not only your problem. Everyone who starts learning recursion first time, he/she will face this. The main thing is nothing but just visualization. Literally it's tough though.

If you try to visualize any recursion code by making it handy(using pen and paper), you will just see that "Oh!, it's working". But you should know that most of recursions have a recurrence relation. Based on that, the function recurs. Similarly, for finding all the the subsets of a particular set, there is a recurrence relation.That is the following...

By taking a particular item + By not taking that item

Here in your code, "Taking a particular item" implies "Push_back" and "Not taking a particular item" implies "Pop_back". That's it.

One of the possibility is, taking no item. We call it  *Null set* .
Another possibility is, taking all the items. Here {0,1,2}.

From permutation combination theory, we can calculate the number of subsets. That is 2<sup>n</sup>, where n is number of items. Here n=3. So the number of subsets will be 2<sup>3</sup> = 8.

For 0, take it or throw it , possibilities = 2
For 1, take it or throw it , possibilities = 2
For 2, take it or throw it , possibilities = 2

So,total number of subsets is 2*2*2 = 8 (including *Null Set*).
If you discard the   *Null Set* , so the total number of subsets will be 8-1 = 7.

That's the theory behind your recursion code.