# Can anyone explain what they mean by "process subset" under if(k == n)?

Tags: recursion, subset

Referring to this stack overflow post here:
[Can someone explain how recursion works when finding all subsets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56925250/can-someone-explain-how-recursion-works-when-finding-all-subsets/58359382?noredirect=1#comment103071180_58359382)

Comment: It means "the subset data member has taken one of the values we wanted to generate, so now you should do something with it". So some _process_ function will be called with each subset value in turn.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math problem instead of a programming problem.